# Recommend me a hosting solution for Rails 3.1 (ruby 1.9.2+) apps / alternative to Heroku

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, hosting, cloud-hosting

I am wondering about the best hosting for Rails 3.1 app based on ruby 1.9.2+. Firstly I tried Site5. Unfortunately, in the time when I tried it, they supported only ruby 1.8.7 and also, the app ran me there a bit slowly.

Then I tried (and still use) Heroku. The deployment is comfortable and that't what I absolutely the most like. But when my app use only 1 dyno, so in a moments is the app so slow (idle dyno) -> the solution are 2 dynos. But in this case - the buying second dynos costs ±$35/montly - this is not so cheap.

So I would like to ask you about your experiences - what do you prefer? Could you recommend me a good hosting solution or any Heroku like site (I know EngineYard)?

My requirements: fast run of an app, easy deployment and acceptable monthly price.

Thanks for your views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, my personal best experience belongs to Engine Yard, which at least meets your first 2 requirements.

It is pricy comparing with Linode and Heroku(w/ a few dynos). If you want to choose one between EY and AWS, I will say definitely EY, which is a bit more expensive than AWS(actually it is based on Amazon EC2), but much more convenient in terms of deployment.

You shall give a trial on EY's free 500 hours and experience it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/a3/) to ping your app every couple minutes or so. That will prevent the 1 web-dyno from going idle. If that is your only issue this may be enough.

On the other hand you could also use [Linode](http://www.linode.com/) or [Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) of course but it will not be as easy to deploy/maintain as Heroku is. Hope that helps.